# How to save downloaded file on sd card from download manager programmatically on android

Tags: android, android-sdcard, android-internet

In my application i have download(Image) feature which is used to download file from urls. The download happen should be shown in notification bar so that i used Download Manager class to download file. This is working fine but the downloaded image does not stored no where in the sdcard.

i have referred the [**url**](http://android-er.blogspot.in/2011/07/sample-code-using-androidappdownloadman.html) for the download manager.

**my requirement is i need to save the download image to sdcard with notification bar indication.**  **What to modify on the code to get save image on sdcard on the above link**

i have some doubts regards the code in the above link is Can i use the same code to download audio or video file?

please help me.

Edited question:

I have tried

```
        filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/download/cm.png";
        Uri destinationUri = Uri.parse(filepath);
        request.setDestinationUri(destinationUri);
```

before the preference manger on the button click. but i could not get the file on sdcard.

Comment: as long as its a http download you can download any type of file

Comment: thanks, but how can i get to save the content from the code?

Comment: default they are saved in cache folder. As njzk2 has pointed out, you have to use either setDestinationUri ,setDestinationInExternalPublicDir or setDestinationInExternalFilesDir

Comment: will [this](http://www.mediafire.com/?xlt6s61v14d38x7) help?

Comment: did you do it before enqueue call?

Comment: yes, but it says illegal arguments error on the path

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is what i used.

```
        Uri downloadUri = Uri.parse(DOWNLOAD_FILE);
        DownloadManager.Request request = new DownloadManager.Request(downloadUri);
        request.setDescription("Downloading a file");
        long id =  downloadManager.enqueue(request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI |DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
                .setTitle("File Downloading...")
                .setDescription("Image File Download")
                .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "cm.png"));
```

Comment: I don't think this would work?
It will save  your file into default Download folder on Phone memory rather than save on your memory card ?
And one more thing 
long id =  downloadManager.enqueue(request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI |DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE)
                .setAllowedOverRoaming(false)
                .setTitle("File Downloading...")
                .setDescription("Image File Download")
                .setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "cm.png")); ==> the enqueue() function return long value? ???

Comment: will setDestinationInExternalPublicDir work if device doesn't have sd card ?

Answer (score 2):

In the code you refer to, the file is opened at the end. At this point, you can consider copying it to the SDCard.

Otherwise (better) use http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DownloadManager.Request.html setDestinationUri(android.net.Uri) to specify where you want to download the file.

Comment: i have tried and used the setDestination(...) on the button click but i could not get. please see my edited question.

Comment: this won't work. Use Uri.fromFile rather than Uri.parse unless you add file:// at the begining of the path

Comment: i have tried 

   filepath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath()+"/cm.png";
   File fileNew = new File(filepath);
   Uri destinationUri = Uri.fromFile(fileNew);
But still no save on sdcard.

Comment: finally i got with setDestinationInExternalPublic. please see my answer. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

```
    downloadmanager = (DownloadManager) context.getSystemService(Context.DOWNLOAD_SERVICE);
    Toast.makeText(context, "Downloading...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Uri uri = Uri.parse("---- url here ------");
    request = new DownloadManager.Request(uri);
    request.setAllowedNetworkTypes(DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_WIFI | DownloadManager.Request.NETWORK_MOBILE);
    request.setAllowedOverRoaming(false);
    request.setTitle("---- title here ------");
    String mimeType = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl("---- url here ------");
    request.setMimeType(mimeType);
    request.setDescription("---- descripation here ------");
    if("---- titlehere ------" != null){
        request.setDestinationInExternalPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS, "---- title here ------");
    }

    request.setNotificationVisibility(DownloadManager.Request.VISIBILITY_VISIBLE_NOTIFY_COMPLETED);
    Long reference = downloadmanager.enqueue(request);
```

Comment: try to explain what you do and how you do that. answers with many code and without explanation are not good.